# Reading P2 card with standard PC Card (PCMCIA) reader

Tags: memory-card, card-reader, pcmcia

I have a Panasonic professional video camera which uses P2 cards.

Looking for a way to connect them to the computer without using the camera, I found that the only P2 reader in the market is the one released by the same manufacturer. Going deeper in my researches, I concluded that a P2 card is simply in a PC Card closure with a special controller and SD cards inside.

So now i'm wondering if a generic USB PCMCIA card reader (much more affordable, although they aren't yet very common, and you find lots of PCMCIA cards to get extra USBs instead of that) [like one of which are shown in that images](http://bridgeurl.com/sample-images-for-usb-pcmcia-card-reader) will allow me to do that - obviously with the P2 driver installed in the PC.

Comment: Searching the net for: "USB card reader CardBus" gets several hits of adapters you can use. Example: http://www.amtron.com/reader/pciecb110.htm which even includes info about Panasonic P2 Driver installation (scroll down).

Comment: Thank you all guys, I'll take a look at your postings calmly later

Comment: @Brian, this is an internal PCIe adapter, I was talking about USB interface.

Comment: If you have found a proper solution to your issue yourself, feel free to post your own answer. If an existing answer gave you the right idea (but didn't include the correct solution in itself), reference it in your answer. If you need further assistance with your question, please join us on [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/118/root-access).

Comment: Well Oliver, because I'm very curious on finding the answer to what I've asked, I'll keep this open until the last day of the bounty, I'll be glad to thank someone with the points. If no one knows about it, I'll ask the question saying that I'll solve the problem in another way. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 76 views and the superuser community not knowing about any techical reference or use case that could demonstrate if that will work, I'll treat the question as "excessively specific" and not contributive.

Anyway, if anyone is in the same case, and as @SmirksWhileWalkingWCabaretGirl pointed, a workaround for my needs is take advantage of the ExpressCard34 slot of the laptop and look for a CardBus to ExpressCard34 converter, which is more much easy to find and much more affordable.

Comment: I'll keep the answer as community wiki, everyone feel free to improve it!

Answer (score -1):

www.walmart.com/ip/13214912?adid=22222222227000295696&wmlspartner=wlpa&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=&wl3=13686856630&wl4=&wl5=pla&veh=sem

It is harder to get cheaper than $50 like the $45 WalMart wants for that Addonics and I swear by  Addonics for their reliability but they have something else no one else has.... good tech support that actually answers questions on the rare occasions you'd ever need one since their stuff just works.

Youre right about the bitttechun transfer rate cause my brother is in vid production and while shoulder surfing one day i WITNESSED this ungodly fast transfer rate of some multi gig files while tapping his shoulder to hurry up we gotta get to the pub and he says just hang on a minute and I'm protesting why "that would take forever to copy files that large.... " but the copy finsihed before I could stop whining.

A good tip off for you and anyone else reading this after you realized I solved your problem, notice the gold stripe on your example pic, that is one of the few industry standards you can rely on as consistent as it indicates a PCCard (PCMCIA II) capable card and is a requisite for any PCMICIA device faster than a modem cause the data transfer rate can be 50+ times faster over PCCard than older PCMCIA cards that will feel like watching elderly snails screwing as files lumber along. It has to be mentioned since there are still old PCMCIA 1 standard adapters even still for sale capable of mounting large capacity CF and SD/SDC cards that seem to insult data transfer instead of facilitating it.

You're welcome to insist just on PCCard or USB 2.0, but it won't properly serve your cards transfer  capabilities as well as that PCExpress card.  Is your requirement for PCCard / USB interface because you don't have an Express2 slot ?

I hope not since you'd be facing the same legacy tax shoppers of IDE SSD's encounter just like car owners with freon Air conditioners get slapped with as mechanics sypmpathejically shake their heads explaiaing the rules, blah, blah.  You're not gonna get the best of both worlds and Googlefu would've exposed any RadioShack soldering tricks to enable cheap, safe conversions of a PCMCIA adapter for this fastazzer card you're flipping back and forth in your hand at this very moment researching the ultimately cheap alternative.

Comment: Might you be able to edit this a bit to just address the question without all the... extras? There's some good information in here, but it's just way too much storytelling around the actual info. If I were visiting this page from a google search or something, I'd take one look at your answer and be like "nope!" even though it's actually useful on the inside. Please [edit] it to more specifically address the question.